# What is the git equivilant of merging a range of revisions in SVN - rebase or cherry pick?

Tags: git, version-control

Transitioning from SVN - what sometimes happens, is that either a 2nd branch or maybe trunk has had a specific range of revisions committed and I need to merge those revisions into my local branch.

Correct me if Im wrong, but I think I would possibly do a merge with rebase?  I also was reading about VSTS and "cherry pick"
eg.  git cherry-pick d34bcef...86d2aec 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/cherry-pick?tabs=command-line

Comment: Both can be used to achieve the same thing, but the end result is slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, both `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` are equal to merging a range of revisions in SVN.

The commands `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` are flexible to apply changes from a commit, a range of commits, commits on a branch etc to the top of a commit/revision.

To apply a range of commits/revision, you can use any of below commands:

```
git rebase --onto <where> <start> <end>
git cherry-pick <start>..<end>
```

More details, you can refer [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) and [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).